# Bind gridview inside of usercontrol from content page

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

hi is it possible to bind gridview inside of usercontrol from content page, if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the easiest way would be to expose the bind in the user control and then call it from your page.

```
//in user control, add this method
public void BindGrid()
{
    gvInnerGrid.DataBind();
}

//on your page
userControl.BindGrid();
```

Comment: Hi it works thank you. I need to pass IQueryable object in order to bind GridView with data. And then to query this object inside of user control. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: You could use the same method to pass the data. Personally I would make a public property on the user control that exposes the grid's DataSource.
ex.

//user control
public object DataSource{get{return gvInnerGrid.DataSource;} set {gvInnerGrid.DataSource = value;}}